# Expresso store - {order_date} in 2011-04-15T17:58:41.000000 format

Tags: expresso-store, date

We need to export the date of orders into a CRM and it needs to be in the following format:

2011-04-15T17:58:41.000000

The current {order_date} is exported in unix format, is it easy to change this or is there any other way I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it supports the format="" parameter as per ExpressionEngine's documentation:

{order_date format="%D, %F %d, %Y - %g:%i:%s"}

Comment: Correct. EE actually handles the date formatting automatically (any number which looks like a unix timestamp can use the `format=""` parameter), so you can always do this with dates.